# Can I get user location on a Qt Desktop application?

Tags: qt, geolocation, positioning

I read that the **OS X** can get the approximate user location using the Wi-Fi network.

There is some way that I can get the user location on a **Qt Desktop** application?

I basically need to get the user location (latitude and longitude) to calculate the sunrise and sunset time.

**Note**: the application will run on **Windows** and **OS X**.

---

**Update**:

I tried to add `Qt += positioning` to my **.pro** file and use the following code:

```
QGeoPositionInfoSource *source1 = QGeoPositionInfoSource::createDefaultSource(this);

if (source1)
{
    qDebug() << "Test1";
}

QGeoAreaMonitorSource *source2 = QGeoAreaMonitorSource::createDefaultSource(this);

if (source2)
{
    qDebug() << "Test2";
}

QGeoSatelliteInfoSource *source3 = QGeoSatelliteInfoSource::createDefaultSource(this);

if (source3)
{
    qDebug() << "Test3";
}
```

But no source (source1, source2, source3) is valid.

I'm currently running it on a Macbook Pro with internet connection (don't know if it matters).

Comment: You might want to have a look at Qt Positioning (Qt >=5.2 from what I can find). It looks it supports both Windows and OSX according to this: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtpositioning-index.html
Some examples: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/location-positioning-cpp.html

Comment: Depends what you mean by internet connection. If it is wired, it most probably won't work, you'll need at least WIFI.
Also from the release notes, you need QT >=5.6 for mac support.

Comment: Thanks @Leherenn. I didn't saw that. I am connected by WIFI but I'm working on Qt 5.3.